# Count cell change only when its empty and not when there is data it in it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a counting script that works great but sometimes I need to change the existing value in the cell and I don't want the script to count that as a entry.

The reason for that is because I use the script to count the amount of booked meetings I have done and don't want the script to count rebooked/rescheduled meetings.

So when I book a meeting a put in the booked date and counts it as a booked meeting, when I need to reschedule or rebook the meeting I change the existing date.

Is there a way to only make it count if the cell is blank and not when it has existing value in it?

Here is the script I use

```
const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
const countColumn = 1; // column G
const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
if (!e.value
|| sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
|| e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
|| e.range.columnStart !== 5) {
return;
}
// increment count
const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn);
countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.oldvalue to check the previous value. For example adding in the if clause `|| e.oldvalue == ""`

Comment: Okay and how does that work then? So if it checks for the old value, find old value and it don't make the count? It feels like there should be a condition besides checking for the old value?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I made myself clear. What I was thinking is to add it inside your already existing if return clause

Comment: I understood that and I tried to put in there but nothing happen so that is why I was thinking that maybe there should be more conditions. I'm not good a this but what I'm thinking is (and please correct me if Im wrong) that there is no instructions on what to do if it finds the old value? There are only instructions on what to do if it finds any value